# R grid graphics: reducing resolution of raster image / grob

Tags: r, graphics, resolution, tiff, r-grid

There is a couple of options for reading images in `tiff` format into *R*, including `library(tiff)`, but also `library(magick)`, `library(terra)` (as the successor of `raster`) and `library(EBImage)`.

I would only like to down-scale/downsample the original `tiff` images to a lower resolution for later `ggplot` output to `PDF`.

Which would be the simplest, most portable (across operating systems) way with the fewest dependencies?

Intuitively, I would assume that actually `library(grid)` would be the most basic and native version (which I probably do already depend on for `ggplot` output anyway), but I'm not sure whether it provides functionality for scaling.

Comment: What have you tried and what are the programming problems or issues?

Comment: I used `system.time()` to compare the time needed for generating PDF output of the images. When using `readTIFF()`, it takes roughly half the time (24 seconds) of magick's `image_read()` function. However, when scaling the image to half of the original size, using magick is again faster.